# Carbon Timezone and format not working together

Tags: php, php-carbon

Here is my code

```
$time = '2019-12-16T10:14:35.000000Z';

$var = new Carbon($time);

$var = $var->setTimezone('Asia/Dhaka')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The return I am expecting is '**2019-12-16 4:14:35**'

The return I am getting '**2019-12-16 10:14:35**'

If I remove the format function, I am getting the right timezone '**2019-12-16T4:14:35.000000Z**'

Clearly the setTimeZone is not working with Format. What am I missing here?

I know there might be possible duplicate issue, but none of the solutions seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source timestamp always in `UTC` timezone.
so change your code to:

```php
$var = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'UTC');
$var = $var->setTimezone('Asia/Dhaka');
```

Comment: Tried that. Not working. Returns the UTC time instead of the updated timezone.

Comment: @Scarecrow changed answer . try it :)

Comment: Great. Now I know what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone like this

```php
$time = '2019-12-16T10:14:35.000000Z'; 
$var = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time, 'Asia/Dhaka');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Madrid');
$var = $var->setTimezone('Asia/Dhaka');
```